# Why is there a low gravity anomaly right next to a high gravity anomaly next to mascons on the Moon?

Tags: gravity, isostasy, earth-moon

[image: A Diagram of gravity in the vicinity of Mare Sereniatis]

This is from the book "*Isosatsy and Flexure of the Atmosphere*" by A. B. Watts. According to him, evidence for the isostatic compensation of mascons (i.e. regions of higher density material in the Moon's crust) should induce a low gravity anomaly right next to the high gravity anomaly above the mascon. Measurements show that it indeed does. But how would compensation create this low anomaly? My thinking is, that compensation means, there is less moon crust material under the mascon than right beside it. But would that not mean, there is heavier mantle material instead right beneath of it? I would be happy if someone shine light upon my confusion.